# How to collect data to single row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have table **Risks** and history table **Risks_history**. 
In Risks table i have data like below:

```
-----------------------------
| ID | DealID | Description |
-----------------------------
| 1  | 14     | Risk1       |
-----------------------------
| 2  | 14     | Risk2       |
-----------------------------
| 3  | 14     | Risk3       |
-----------------------------
| 4  | 15     | Risk4       |
-----------------------------
```

So here is we can see that one deal can have several Risks. I need to save data of table **Risks** in history like below:

```
-------------------------------------
| ID | dealID |   AllDescriptions   |   
-------------------------------------
| 1  | 14     | Risk1, Risk2, Risk3 |
-------------------------------------
| 2  | 15     | Risk4               |
-------------------------------------
```

I need trigger that will do it. But now I cant.

How I can collect data from several rows into one row?

**EDIT:**

I need trigger, so now i have below trigger:

```
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[Risks_history]
      (
            DealID,
            [AllDescription]
      )
      SELECT 
            [DealID],
            stuff((select ',' + i.name from inserted i
                   where i.DealID= i2.DealID
                   FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as Description                                          
        FROM inserted i2;
```

But in table **Risks_history** i have data(which trigger wrote) like below:

```
 - When I change Risk1:

    -------------------------------------
    | ID | dealID |   AllDescriptions   |   
    -------------------------------------
    | 1  | 14     | Risk1, Risk1, Risk1 |
    -------------------------------------

 - When I change Risk2:

-------------------------------------
| ID | dealID |   AllDescriptions   |   
-------------------------------------
| 1  | 14     | Risk2, Risk2, Risk2 |
-------------------------------------

 - When I change Risk3:

-------------------------------------
| ID | dealID |   AllDescriptions   |   
-------------------------------------
| 1  | 14     | Risk3, Risk3, Risk3 |
-------------------------------------
```

But I need to write all Risks whatever risk changing

Comment: Group by then use stuff or substring

Comment: I tried. but could't

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this..

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      DealID
    , STUFF((
        SELECT N', ' + CAST([Description] AS VARCHAR(4000))
        FROM Risks R2
        WHERE R1.DealID = R2.DealID
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE), 1, 2, '') AS AllDescriptions   
FROM Risks R1
GROUP BY DealID
```

Your modified trigger and assuming DealID and Description are column names of Risks tables,

```
DECLARE @DealID INT;

SELECT 
    @DealID = [DealID]                                         
FROM inserted;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Risks_history]
      (
            DealID,
            [AllDescription]
      )
      SELECT 
            [DealID],
            STUFF((
                SELECT ', ' + R2.[Description]
                FROM Risks R2
                WHERE R1.DealID = R2.DealID
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE), 1, 2, '') AS AllDescriptions                                        
        FROM Risks R1
        WHERE DealID = @DealID
    GROUP BY DealID
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer accoding to modfied question

Comment: I have updated your trigger. If its not working,  please attach the records of table Risks

Comment: Its not working. I gave you examples of data in tables above

Comment: I have updated the query based on the data and column names above

Answer (score 2):

```
create table #c

( ID int, DealID int, Description varchar(10))
insert into #c values
(1,14,'Risk1'),
(2,14,'Risk2'),
(3,14,'Risk3'),
(4,15,'Risk4')

SELECT DISTINCT DealID,
                STUFF((SELECT ','+Description   
                       FROM #c t1 
                       WHERE t1.DealID = t2.DealID 
                        FOR XML PATH(''))
                       ,1,1,'') as Description   
FROM #c t2
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer accoding to modfied question

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', '  + CAST(Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM Risks
    WHERE (ID = RiskMain.ID) 
FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE), 1, 2, '') AS AllDescriptions  
FROM Risks RiskMain
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer accoding to modfied question

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tblTest AS TABLE
 (
   ID  INT,
   DealID INT,
   Description VARCHAR(50)
 )  

 INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES(1,14,'Risk1')
 ,(2,14,'Risk2')
 ,(3,14,'Risk3')
 ,(4,15,'Risk4')

 SELECT STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Description) 
            FROM @tblTest c
            --WHERE c.DealID=T.DealID   
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

 SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(T.ID)) AS ID,
    T.DealID,
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + Description 
            FROM @tblTest c
            WHERE c.DealID=T.DealID 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')) AS AllDescriptions
FROM @tblTest T
GROUP BY T.DealID
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer accoding to modfied question

Answer (score 1):

You can get this output with one single SQL query like this:

```
SELECT t1.DealID,
Descriptions =REPLACE( (SELECT Description AS [data()]
FROM Risks_history t2
WHERE t2.DealID = t1.DealID
ORDER BY Description
FOR XML PATH('')
), ' ', ',')
FROM Risks_history t1
GROUP BY DealID ;
```

Now you have to put this query under the trigger to insert filter data into your table.

[image]

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer accoding to modfied question

Answer (score 0):

We can use MIN in the ID and DealID in GROUP BY:

```
SELECT MIN(u.ID) AS ID, 
    u.DealID,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + A.Description FROM Mytable A
    WHERE A.DealID=u.DealID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As [Description]
FROM Mytable u
GROUP BY u.DealID
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer accoding to modfied question