# How to create a single string in SQL, based on Hierarchical Data - CTE and XML?

Tags: sql, xml, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a database table storing stock locations for various products.

One part number can have several Departments, each department can have several racks and so on (shelves and then rows).

I need to concatenate this information to fit the dataset on label (on a single line).

To retrieve the dataset my query is as follows.

```
select d.Department_Name, r.Rack_Name, s.Shelf_Name, rw.Row_Name from Part_Locator l
join Part_Numbers p
  on l.Part_Id=p.Part_Id
join PL_Departments d
  on l.Department_Id=d.Department_Id
join PL_Racks r
  on l.Rack_Id=r.Rack_Id
join PL_Shelfs s
  on l.Shelf_Id=s.Shelf_Id
join PL_Rows rw
  on l.Row_Id=rw.Row_Id
where p.Part_Number='1BODY000997'
```

Results are as follows:

[image: The Results are shown below]

I can make a nested look to build a string, but I believe a combination of recursive CTE, Stuff and XML could so the same for me. So far I can find many examples, but none that I can understand well enough to make them work together application.

The desired output is as follows:

Assembly - Rack IA-10 - Shelf A - Row 1,2,3,4,5,6 - Shelf B - Row 1,2,3,4,5,6 - Shelf C - Row 1,2,3,4,5,6

I am not opposed to changing that format as long as it reads logically. Also please note there can multiple departments.

Any help to get me going in the right direction would be great.
Thanks in advance!

I was able to get this working using cursor. I also created a view to remove the joins from the query, much easier to read.

```
    DECLARE
@partnumber varchar(50)='1BODY000997', @dept varchar(50), @rack varchar(50), @shelf varchar(50), @row varchar(50), @text varchar(500)='';

 DECLARE department_cursor CURSOR FOR
 SELECT DISTINCT Department_Name FROM Part_Locations WHERE Part_Number=@partnumber
 OPEN department_cursor;
 FETCH NEXT FROM department_cursor INTO @dept; 
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN 
 SET @text=@text+CAST(@dept as varchar(50))+' - ';
    DECLARE rack_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT Rack_Name FROM Part_Locations WHERE Part_Number=@partnumber AND Department_Name=@dept
    OPEN rack_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM rack_cursor INTO @rack
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   
    SET @text=@text+'Rack:'+CAST(@rack as varchar(50))+' - ';
        DECLARE shelf_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT Shelf_Name FROM Part_Locations WHERE Part_Number=@partnumber AND Department_Name=@dept AND Rack_Name=@rack
        OPEN shelf_cursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM shelf_cursor INTO @shelf
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN       
        SET @text=@text+'Shelf:'+CAST(@shelf as varchar(50))+' (Row ';      
            SET @text=@text+(SELECT abc=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Row_Name FROM Part_Locations WHERE Part_Number=@partnumber AND Department_Name=@dept AND Rack_Name=@rack AND Shelf_Name=@shelf FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''))          
            SET @text=@text+') ';  
        FETCH NEXT FROM shelf_cursor INTO @shelf
        END;
        CLOSE shelf_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE shelf_cursor;   
    FETCH NEXT FROM rack_cursor INTO @rack
    END;
    CLOSE rack_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE rack_cursor;
  FETCH NEXT FROM department_cursor INTO @dept;
 END
 CLOSE department_cursor;
 DEALLOCATE department_cursor;
 PRINT (@text)
```

this gives me good output of..

Assembly - Rack:IA-10 - Shelf:A (Row 1,2,3,4,5,6) Shelf:B (Row 1,2,3,4,5,6) Shelf:C (Row 1,2,3,4,5,6)

Comment: Many ways to do this. Is this SQL Server? If so, check out this duplicate ... 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40152481/how-to-collect-data-to-single-row-in-sql-server

Comment: @Excelnoobster, Yes this is MS SQL. Your example is good, but I need to iterate through multiple levels, not just one. This is where I am struggling.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @Excelnoobster, No I haven't. Not sure how I can dig down for 4 layers.

Comment: what would the desired output be for more two departments, with two racks in each?

Comment: @Excelnoobster Something like Assembly - Rack IA-10 - Shelf A - Row 1,2,3,4,5,6 - Shelf B - Row 1,2,3,4,5,6 - Shelf C - Row 1,2,3,4,5,6 - Production - Rack IP-2 - Shelf A - Row 1,2,3,4,5,6 - Shelf B - Row 1,2,3,4,5,6 - Shelf C - Row 1,2,3,4,5,6

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you could do a cte, or you could do a running field (similar to running total) , or xml path. Actually, forget the running field, too hard.  Below are two examples , one with xml, followed by a cte. I used in that link I sent earlier to the the xml path. Due to the complexity, I needed to do two xml paths ( first one into a temp table)

Note that I created a table (ITEMS) and put your results into it ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.Dept, i.rack, i.shelf,
    stuff(  (   select ',' + i2.rowname
                from ITEMS i2   
            where i2.Dept = i.Dept and
            i2.rack = i.rack and
            i2.shelf =i.shelf
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as RownumbersCommaSeparated
INTO #T1
FROM ITEMS i

SELECT 
    stuff(  (   select ' ' +  T.Dept + ' Rack ' + T.rack + ' Shelf ' + T.shelf + ' Rows ' + T.RownumbersCommaSeparated
                from #T1 T
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'' )   as DesiredOutput
```

The common table expression is a bit longer !  There are TWO recursions ...

```
;

WITH
    CTE0 AS
        (   
            SELECT i.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.Dept,i.rack,i.shelf, i.rowname) recordnumber,
            RANK() OVER (  ORDER BY i.Dept,i.rack,i.shelf) Parent,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.Dept,i.rack,i.shelf ORDER BY i.Dept,i.rack,i.shelf,i.rowname) rowidForeachParent
            FROM ITEMS i

        ),
    CTE1 AS
        (   SELECT 
                 i.Parent,
                    i.Dept + ' Rack ' + 
                    i.rack + ' Shelf ' + 
                    i.shelf + ' Rows ' as CoreData,
                    MAX(i.rowidforeachparent) maxrowidforeachparent
                     FROM cte0 i
                     group by i.Parent, i.Dept, i.rack, i.shelf
        ),
    CTE2 AS
        (
            SELECT
                i1.Parent,
                i1.maxrowidforeachparent,
                  CAST( i1.CoreData +  ',' + i0.rowname  AS varchar(MAX) )  as outputX,
                   i0.rowidForeachParent
            FROM cte1 i1
            join cte0 i0 on 
                i0.Parent = i1.Parent AND
                I0.rowidForeachParent = 1

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
            i1.Parent,
            i1.maxrowidforeachparent,
                i1.outputX +  ',' + i0.rowname, 
                i0.rowidForeachParent
            FROM cte2 i1
            join cte0 i0 on 
                i0.Parent = i1.Parent AND
                I0.rowidForeachParent = I1.rowidForeachParent+1
        ) ,

    CTE3 AS
        (

            SELECT i.outputX ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Parent) ParentId
             FROM  cte2 i 
            where i.rowidForeachParent = i.maxrowidforeachparent
        ),

    CTE4 AS
        (
            SELECT outputX, i3.ParentId FROM CTE3 i3 
            where i3.ParentId = 1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT i4.outputX + ' ' + i3.outputX, i3.ParentId FROM CTE3 i3 
            join CTE4 i4 on i3.ParentId = i4.ParentId + 1

        )

        select top 1 * from cte4 order by ParentId desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will give your examples a try. I did manage to get this working yesterday by using a cursor, something I hadn't thought of. I will add it to my original post.